# Problems with defining @shops variable NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I've created two user models called "user" and "shop".  When I try to use the @shop variable as shop (like in shop.name) it will not work, but user.name will work.  So I missed defining shop at some point, and cannot figure out where to fix it.

Here's the error I get:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
  app/views/shops/index.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_shops_index_html_erb__1785913569146145211_70081842378680'
  app/views/shops/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_shops_index_html_erb__1785913569146145211_70081842378680'
```

This index page for user works:
**user/index.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

But this one for shops does not b/c of `shop.name`:
**shop/index.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'All shops') %>
<h1>All shops</h1>

<ul class="shops">
  <% @shops.each do |shop| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to shop.name, shop %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Here is the shops controller: **shops_controller.rb**

```
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  #add before action for index
  before_action :correct_shop, only: [:edit, :update]

    def index
      @shops = Shop.all
    end

    def show
      @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @shop = Shop.new
    end

    def create
      @shop = Shop.new(shop_params)
      if @shop.save
        shop_log_in @shop
        flash[:success] = "Thank you for signing up, welcome to AccessOBD!"
        redirect_to shop_home_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def edit
      @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
      if @shop.update_attributes(shop_params)
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to @shop
      else
          render 'edit'
      end
    end

    private

    def shop_params
      params.require(:shop).permit(:name, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :email, :phone, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation, :picture)
    end

    def correct_shop
      @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_shop?(@shop)
    end
end
```

And here is the session helper for shops: **ShopSessionsHelper.rb**

```
module ShopSessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given shop.
  def shop_log_in(shop)
    session[:shop_id] = shop.id
  end

  # Remembers a shop in a persistent session.
  def shop_remember(shop)
    shop.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:shop_id] = shop.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = shop.remember_token
  end

  def current_shop?(shop)
    shop == current_shop
  end

  # Returns the shop corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_shop
    if (shop_id = session[:shop_id])
      @current_shop ||= Shop.find_by(id: shop_id)
    elsif (shop_id = cookies.signed[:shop_id])
      shop = Shop.find_by(id: shop_id)
      if shop && shop.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        shop_log_in shop
        @current_shop = shop
      end
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the shop is logged in, false otherwise.
  def shop_logged_in?
    !current_shop.nil?
  end

  def shop_forget(shop)
    shop.forget
    cookies.delete(:shop_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Logs out the current shop.
  def shop_logout
    shop_forget(current_shop)
    session.delete(:shop_id)
    @current_shop = nil
  end

  # Redirects to stored location (or to the default).
  def shop_redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(shop)
    session.delete(:forwarding_url)
  end

  # Stores the URL trying to be accessed.
  def store_location
    session[:forwarding_url] = request.url if request.get?
  end
end
```

index.html.erb former

```
  <% @shops.each do |shop| %>
    <li>
      <div class= "shop-name pull-left">
      <%= link_to shop.name, shop %>
        <% if current_shop.admin? && !current_shop?(shop) %>
        | <%= link_to "(Delete Shop)", shop, method: :delete,
                                      data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class= "shop-address pull-right">
      <p><%= shop.address %> <br> <%= shop.city %>, <%= shop.state %> <%= shop.zip %> <br> <%= shop.phone %></p>
      </div>
    </li>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I cannot see where you have assigned `@shops`. Can you please replace `<% @shops.each do |shop| %>` in index.html.erb with `<% Shop.find_each do |shop| %>` and try again?

Comment: @shivam : He said "This index page for user works: user/index.html.erb". You can ignore that one completely, it doesn't add anything to the question, imo.

Comment: can you add `raise @shops.inspect` just above the line: `<% @shops.each` and run it again - so we can see what is actually coming through in `@shops` ?

Comment: Making the changes shivam suggested worked.  I'm wondering if there is some place in an overall controller where I wouldn't have to worry about defining Shop in each instance

Comment: Doing it that way is a code smell (pushing model-fetching into the view-layer is considered bad) - I think @shivam only suggested it just to see if your `Shop` class is broken, or the way you're fetching `@shops`

Comment: @TarynEast thats true. @Virge define `@shops` variable in shoes controller's index method and use your old code in index.html.erb. Everything should work fine

Comment: @shivam could you show me an example of that? I'm not sure what the syntax should be.  `shop = ?`

Comment: Try my answer, you will get nil records with their indexes that would elp you identify and fix them manually(if possible)

Comment: @shivam : But it won't guarantee that the same will not happen somewhere else in the app. Think its better to fix the real cause.

Comment: @TarynEast I added the raise line on the original code, and the whole list of shops came through with the raise line on top.  removed the raise line and it's working fine now.  No idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your records are nil, to identify them run the following code, you will get index values of those records

```
<% @shops.each_with_index do |shop, index| %>
  <li>
    <% unless shop.blank? %>
      <%= link_to shop.name, shop %>
    <% else %>
      <%= "Record nil at " + index.to_s %>
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: the `each` *should* mean that you just don't call the loop... it seems like, (oddly), @shops is not empty, but has nil values in it somehow

Comment: The shops all have their fields filled, error messages & validations would have caught any blanks. not sure if there is something weird going on like Taryn mentioned

Comment: But as you mentioned in the question you are getting `NoMethodError (undefined method name' for nil:NilClass)` error right?

Comment: @VirgeAssault You are missing the point. The code in the answer is not attempting to determine whether "shops have their fields filled". It is attempting to address the problem of the `@shops` variable containing nil.

Comment: @MikeSlutsky and why might shops contain nil? I'm new, not following

Comment: @VirgeAssault You are getting NilClass error because @shops has nil records, try `nil.name` in your console you will get the same error

Comment: @VirgeAssault - we have no idea why your `@shops` has nil values either... first we seek to confirm, then to figure out why - and then we can figure out how to fix the problem.

Comment: @TarynEast I'm confused because the error I get is `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]` but the link is going to /users/3 and is passing parameters {"id"=>"3"}.  So how can the id be nil?  I'm new to this and the comments aren't super comprehensive, so I'm having a hard time understanding

Comment: Sounds like a new question :) probably best asked as a question instead of of a comment.